# How do I get maven to "stamp" a build number into a properties file

Tags: maven-2

I would like to be able to, as part of a maven build, set the build number (doesn't matter exactly what) in a properties file/class (so I can show it in a UI). Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We used the [Build Number Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/) now available from Codehaus. It can generate a sequential build number or allows you to use the time stamp.

Answer (score 2):

The [Maven build number plugin](http://technology.amis.nl/blog/?p=2582) should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I use the maven-property-plugin to store the CruiseControl build label in a properties file (the build label is is available as a system property named 'label').

[A post](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnsmart/archive/2008/03/using_hudson_en.html) on how to do this with Hudson.